# Помогите сделать градиент CSS

Tags: html, css, градиент

[image: Нужно сделать вот такой градиент]

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать вот такой градиент на CSS.

Comment: это не биржа труда

Comment: полностью согласен с @meine - еще хочу дополнить это не градиаент, это паттерн. для того чтобы его сделать нужно вырезать квадрат и клонировать его с помощью css - например background-repeat: repeat-x;

Comment: Но это же не градиент...

Comment: @Suvitruf да, это несколько радиальных градиентов наложенных друг на друга

Comment: @StrangerintheQ век живи - век учись)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это повторение вот такого шаблона:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой можно собрать при помощи css переменных и radial-gradient:

```css
body {
  --c1: lightgray;
  --c2: white;
  
  --pattern: 
          var(--c2) 0px,  var(--c2) 4px,
          var(--c1) 5px,  var(--c1) 14px,
          var(--c2) 15px, var(--c2) 19px,
          var(--c1) 20px, var(--c1) 29px,
          var(--c2) 30px, var(--c2) 34px,
          var(--c1) 35px, var(--c1) 44px,
          var(--c2) 45px, var(--c2) 49px,
          transparent 50px, transparent 100%;
          
  background: 
        radial-gradient(circle at 50px  75px, var(--pattern)), 
        radial-gradient(circle at 0px   50px, var(--pattern)),
        radial-gradient(circle at 100px 50px, var(--pattern)),
        radial-gradient(circle at 50px  25px, var(--pattern));
        
  background-size: 100px 50px
}
```

Comment: Отлично! Код красиво смотрится. Нужно будет мне тоже чаще CSS-переменные применять по прямому назначению, а не только для доступа из JS. :)